# How can I wipe out my local branch in GIT?

Tags: git

I dont' want to deal with any conflicts on my local master branch as the origin (remote) master has changed and I just want 100% of the remote's version.

Is there a way to wipe out the local master? (other than just manually deleting and cloning again).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When on branch 'master', you can simply do

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that you would lose your local changes that way.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I would do it (while on master):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

As evidenced by the other answers, there's more than one way to get this done.
Somehow, to me this just seems the most straightforward.

EDIT: Where'd all the other answers go??